# I am not able to uninstall "Island" app. What should I do now?

Tags: uninstallation, parallel-apps

I installed Island app after some YouTubers said. But it is now not uninstalling itself. Plus it is also not showing in the admin app list. As it gained admin access.

Whenever I try to uninstall it, it shows the error "Can't uninstall active device admin app". I have also checked the admin app list from security settings but it is not even showing there. I am too scared because my phone is rooted and it has gained full access to my phone (I think). My apps are divided into two sections "Personal" and "Work".

Kindly tell me how to uninstall this "Island" app.

Comment: First remove the work profile.

Comment: I can't really remember what's inside the Island app, but wasn't there some kind of uninstallation guide inside the app?